# Заполнение нескольких таблиц с помощью OleDb

Tags: c#, sql, excel, oledb

При выполнении возникает ошибка: "Обнаружены символы за пределами инструкции SQL". Можно ли  нижеприведенным способом заполнить сразу несколько таблиц?

```
var commandString = "SELECT * FROM [Table1$]; SELECT * FROM [Table2$]";

using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(commandString, connectionString))
{
      DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

      adapter.Fill(dataSet);
}
```

Comment: Table1 и Table2 идентичны по структуре? Если нет, то как можно заполнить один dataset разными таблицами?

Comment: Нет, у таблиц разные схемы. Как выяснилось, в данном случае 2 sql команды не могут быть в одной строке, поэтому придётся искать другой способ заполнить DataSet

Comment: Смысл команды SELECT означает "выбрать что-то из того-то по таким то параметрам". Использование конструкции SELECT; SELECT; само по себе неправильно. Видимо вы хотите за один запрос получить данные для двух разных таблиц? Но придется запрашивать два раза. Ошибка возникает сразу же за первой ";". Один SELECT = один запрос = один набор данных для одной заполняемой таблицы.